# Is using VPN more secured when working remotly? Is using VPN more secure when working at the office?

Tags: vpn

I'm new to the company I work in. This company advise me to connect to the internet using a VPN **when I work remotely**, but *also* **when I work in the office**. I've been told it is for security reasons. I am bewildered!

Why is it more secure to do so?

Is there some security issues that might arise?

I've looked around on internet, and apart from VPN companies that try to sell their service, I haven't really found anything answering the question.

Comment: Have you asked your company? It's their requirement. They might know the specific threats they are concerned about.

Comment: Just a guess: in the office they use a Wifi system, correct? Then may be they have decided to simplify their network security and do not implement Special measures for their Wifi network, instead they just use the VPN system. Alternatively it might just be that they want the users to learn to use VPN and inside the company network VPN is not really necessary but it does no harm and trains the users.

Comment: There are too much unknowns here: What kind of VPN is this about in the first place - corporate VPN or consumer VPN? The first is for securing access to corporate infrastructure and for authentication, the latter is for enhancing privacy. Assuming corporate VPN: where is the corporate infrastructure located? Is it in the office you work, in some remote office, in the cloud ... ? If it is not local or if the access infrastructure cannot be trusted then using a VPN here too makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a requirement stemming from the network topology. Since we don't know your network we can only speculate.

You may also need access to remote resources.

I used to work in a somewhat sensitive position and to access some services/servers you had to use a specific VPN profile even from the office, combined with 2FA. Basically the services in question were restricted to certain IP address ranges.

It is also possible that some services like E-mail, more specifically the POP/IMAP servers are not exposed on the public Internet. It is something I have actually implemented. I run a mail server with port 25 open to receive incoming E-mail but IMAP ports are only open to some whitelisted IP addresses, that require VPN.

This is a great way to reduce the **attack surface** if you can afford the "inconvenience" of using VPN.

And in fact you might notice that some features like E-mail or network drives do not work for you if you don't have VPN enabled. But there is a difference between "advise" and "require".

Is the company clueless about security ? Maybe, maybe not. Maybe they know what they are doing, but didn't bother explaining to a non-technical person.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed bizarre that the company advises you to connect to the Internet using a VPN. In general, companies prefer to know who is connecting to them and the VPN break-out point serves somewhat as as an anonymiser.

I would suggest that you make sure that you understood the advise correctly. It is quite normal for companies to tell their employees to connect to the company's servers using a VPN over the Internet and it is likely that this is what they meant.

You may assume that the network in the offices is somehow part of the company network. However, some companies put just plain Internet in their offices. Other companies view the user access network as insecure, because they have limited control over who connects to it (no NAC for example). Connecting from such an insecure network to the company's servers may then require a VPN too.

Comment: *"and the VPN break-out point serves somewhat as as an anonymiser."* - I think you are confusing consumer VPN with corporate VPN: the first is for enhancing privacy, the latter is for securing the connection between the (often company owned) client endpoint and the company infrastructure.

Comment: No. The point is, that the question states "This company advise me to connect **to** the internet using a VPN"; **TO** the internet, not *over* the Internet. All the corporate VPNs that I have seen connect to the company *over* the Internet.

Comment: Since you insist on the wording: Consumer VPN don't connect to the internet either. They have their endpoint somewhere on the internet and require an already existing connection to the internet. Given that companies usually require a VPN to connect into their protected infrastructure I think this is what the OP actually meant.